# Databricks terraform provider - Job-level parameters

Tags: terraform, databricks, terraform-provider-databricks, databricks-workflows

In Databricks, I was able to configure job level parameters via UI and via api 2.1; So far so good, really nice feature.

I was looking into databricks terraform provider and these job-level parameters are not yet supported in terraform. Even though it wasn't documented I tested it, and got an error.

Do you guys have any estimation when this will be released to databricks terraform provider? Let me know if you need more information on this.

Thanks!
Francisco

Tried to use parameters in https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs but it failed as:

│ Error: Unsupported block type
│
│   on main.tf line 368, in resource "databricks_job" "this":
│  368:           dynamic "parameters" {
│
│ Blocks of type "parameters" are not expected here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Job level parameters isn't a public feature, so it's not available in Terraform yet. It will be added as soon as it moves to the public preview or GA status.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, just wanted to have some kind of knowledge on when this would be available!

Comment: No dates yet... Please contact your Databricks account team who enrolled you into this preview